# Making monadic code shorter

Tags: haskell, monads

Consider the following code:

```
transform :: Foo -> Bar
transform foo =
  case foo of
    Foo1 x     -> Foo1 x
    Foo2 x y   -> Foo2 x (transform y)
    Foo3 x y z -> Foo3 x (transform y) (transform z)
```

Now suppose for some reason I change this to work in a monad (e.g., because I have state I want to carry around or whatever). Now we have

```
transform :: Foo -> State Int Bar
transform foo =
  case foo of
    Foo1 x     -> return $ Foo1 x
    Foo2 x y   -> do
      y' <- transform y
      return $ Foo2 x y'
    Foo3 x y z -> do
      y' <- transform y
      z' <- transform z
      return $ Foo3 x y' z'
```

Well that all *works* and everything, but... can we improve this? I have a nagging feeling that I ought to be able to define some nifty infix function to make this look nicer, but every time I try to work out how, my mind goes numb after a while...

Comment: `Foo2 x <$> transform y` and `Foo3 x <$> transform y <*> transform z`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your intuition is right. This is the role of the `ap` function in the `Monad` class, or equivalently of the `<*>` operator in the `Applicative` class, which pretty much all monads implement (and will actually become a superclass of `Monad` in the future).

Here is its type:

```
(<*>) :: (Applicative f) => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

So it basically applies a wrapped function `a -> b` to a wrapped `a` to return a wrapped `b`. It is equivalent to:

```
mf <*> mx = do
  f <- mf
  x <- mx
  return $ f x
```

Here is how to use it in your case, emphasizing the similarity between the different cases:

```
transform foo =
  case foo of
    Foo1 x     -> return Foo1 <*> return x
    Foo2 x y   -> return Foo2 <*> return x <*> transform y
    Foo3 x y z -> return Foo3 <*> return x <*> transform y <*> transform z
```

This can be shortened by considering that `return f <*> return x == return (f x)`:

```
transform foo =
  case foo of
    Foo1 x     -> return $ Foo1 x
    Foo2 x y   -> return (Foo2 x) <*> transform y
    Foo3 x y z -> return (Foo3 x) <*> transform y <*> transform z
```

And even further, by using the operator `<$>` which is equivalent to `fmap` from the `Functor` class:

```
transform foo =
  case foo of
    Foo1 x     -> return $ Foo1 x
    Foo2 x y   -> Foo2 x <$> transform y
    Foo3 x y z -> Foo3 x <$> transform y <*> transform z
```

Comment: I had a feeling this should be possible, but I couldn't quite figure out how all the types fit together... Thanks!

Comment: Technically speaking yes, but since virtually every library defines a `Functor` instance for their `Monad`s, there is not much point in avoiding using `Functor` methods. Almost the same goes for `Applicative`.

Comment: So this is why humans keep saying "use Applicative style"... It makes [some] stuff shorter! :-D

Answer (score 2):

```
transform :: Foo -> State Int Bar
transform foo = 
  case foo of
    Foo1 x -> return $ Foo1 x
    Foo2 x y -> Foo2 x <$> transform y
    Foo3 x y z -> Foo3 x <$> transform y <*> transform z
```

Requires `Control.Applicative` and `Functor`/`Applicative` instances for your Monad (they're there for state, and relatively trivial to implement for other Monads).

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else trying to figure this out...

It seems the crucial definitions are these:

```
mf <*> mx = do
  f <- mf
  x <- mx
  return (f x)

f <$> mx = do
  x <- mx
  return (f x)
```

In particular, the types are different; `<*>` takes `mf` while `<$>` takes `f`:

```
(<*>) :: Monad m => m (x -> y) -> m x -> m y
(<$>) :: Monad m =>   (x -> y) -> m x -> m y
```

(Not, of course, that either of these are actually `Monad` methods, or even methods at all. But you get the idea...)

As somebody who never uses `fmap`, this takes a while to get used to...